# How can I turn a number (regardless of num of digits) within a string to a specific set of characters?

Tags: javascript, string

I have looked for an answer but am unable to find one.

I need a function that will take a string input and output the same string but the number within the string will become "###" or "$$$" when outputted (depending on whether or not there is a dollar sign in front of the number).

Here are some examples of what needs to happen:

```
"Final Price:" ---> "Final Price:"
"Final Price of 3 for " ---> "Final price of ### for "
"Final Price of 27 for " ---> "Final price of ### for "
"Final Price of $12.50" ---> "Final price of $$$"
"Discount of -$8.99" ---> "Discount of -$$$"
"6/" ---> "###/"
"Selling 6-Piece Set" ---> "Selling ###-piece Set"
```

So far I have turned the string into an array based on spaces using split() and then changing elements that have a number in them. However this does not work when the number is not separated by a space (6/ or 4-piece).

Also, regardless of the number of digits the number has, it will always turn to three hashtags "###" or dollar signs "$$$".

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a regular expression replacement.

Comment: @Barmar I was using a regular expression replacement but I found that it would replace each digit so I would have a surplus of hashtags... will take another look though thank you!!!

Comment: Do it in two steps: First replace `$` followed by a number with `$$$`. Then replace any remaining numbers with `###`.

Comment: If the regular expression is `\d+` it should match the entire number at once, not just one digit.

Comment: You'll need a slightly more complex regexp to match a number with a decimal point. You should be able to find examples by searching this site.

Comment: @Barmar okay I will try thank you for your help!

Comment: If you can't get it working, post what you tried. We're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Regex replacment can help replace words containing numbers. Here's how:

```js
var input = "Final Price of 3 for";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w*\d\w*)");

foreach (Match matchVal in matches){
     //Check if number is decimal
      var decimalMatches = matchVal.Value.match(/(\d+)/);
      if(decimalMatches.length > 1) // means there is dot in between numbers
            input.replace(matchVal.Value, "$$$");
      else
            input.replace(matchVal.Value, "###");
}
```